# *.pyc files not being found

Tags: python

I'm writing an application that loads byte-compiled `*.pyc` files under Python 3.3. I am distributing the `*.pyc` files without their corresponding `*.py` files to (try to) protect my source code. (Yes, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368304/what-are-the-limitations-of-distributing-pyc-files), trying to deter decompilation by byte-compiling Python isn't the most secure option, but I can always add other code-security measures if I find I need to.)

However, I have found that Python isn't loading the `*.pyc` files without their original `*.py` files in place. (According to [PEP 3147](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/), the `*.pyc` files are kept in a subdirectory called `__pycache__` in the directory where the `*.py` file would be. I am following this convention with my own code.)

Under an earlier iteration of my project that used Python 2.7, I byte-compiled the Python sources and placed the generated `*.pyc` files into the same directory as the `*.py` files; that worked just fine. Clearly, there is a problem with how Python is finding the `__pycache__` folder. What am I doing wrong? (And yes, I have set `sys.path` appropriately; otherwise it would not be finding the `*.py` file when I insert it as a debugging measure.)

Comment: Do the `.pyc` files thus generated have an extra `.cpython-33.` inserted?  If so, you can simply try renaming them to have the same name as the module.  [This just worked for me, anyhow.]

Comment: @DSM: Did not work. Still can't find the module.

Comment: Hmm.  Works on this end -- I'm looking at a `hello, world!` message generated by importing a `fred.pyc` file I copied from `fred.cpython-33.pyc` from a directory `tmp` I added to `sys.path` after removing every other file.

Comment: Are you ensuring that both the `__pycache__` directory and its content have appropriate permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied the `*.pyc` file out of the `__pycache__` dir and removed `.cpython-33` from its filename; Python then found it as expected. Thanks, DSM!

Answer (score 4):

From [PEP 3147](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/):

> If the py source file is missing, the pyc file inside `__pycache__` will be ignored. This eliminates the problem of accidental stale pyc file imports.
>
> For backward compatibility, Python will still support pyc-only distributions, however it will only do so when the pyc file lives in the directory where the py file would have been, i.e. not in the `__pycache__` directory. pyc file outside of `__pycache__` will only be imported if the py source file is missing.

So, if you want to make pyc-only distributions, you will have to put your compiled files in the same place as the .py files would have gone. According to the PEP, `compileall` has the option of creating this exact layout so you don't have to go copying things out of `__pycache__`, so check it out.